# I have created user and try to login then this error is poping out. 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-3.0

I am getting errors like the title above. I don't where are the mistakes. This is the code for views.py
I have created user and when I try to login the user then this error popout. I am trying to get rid this from yesterday. I am using signal method

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def admin_only(view_fun):
     def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
         group = None
         if request.user.groups.exists():
              group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
          if group == 'customer':
              return redirect('user')
           if group =='admin':
               return view_fun(request, *args, **kwargs)
           return wrapper_function
```

This is the code for views.py. I am debugging this from yesterday.

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.forms import inlineformset_factory  
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as dj_login, 
                                 logout
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from account.models import *
from account.forms import OrderForm, CreateUserForm, 
                           CustomerForm
 from account.filters import OrderFilter
 from account.decorators import unauthenticated_user, 
                            allowed_users, admin_only
 @login_required(login_url='login')
 @admin_only
 def dashboard(request):
     orders = Order.objects.all()
     customers = Customer.objects.all()
     total_customer = customers.count()
     total_order = orders.count()
     delivered = orders.filter(status = 'Delivered').count()
     pending = orders.filter(status = 'Pending').count()

     context= 
             {'orders':orders,'customers':customers,
               'total_order':total_order,
               'delivered':delivered,'pending':pending}
     return render(request,'account/dashboard.html',context)
```

Comment: paste the traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with indentation, as well as no return function when the conditions are not met. So here is how you can fix it:

```
def admin_only(view_fun):
     def wrapper_function(request, *args, **kwargs):
         if request.user.groups.exists():
             group = request.user.groups.all()[0].name
             if group == 'customer':
                 return redirect('user')
             if group =='admin':
                 return view_fun(request, *args, **kwargs)
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/404')  # redirect to 404 page
     return wrapper_function
```

Here I am checking if user is either in customer or admin group, otherwise sending them to 404 page.